# iOS App Crashes in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions due to IBOutlet

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, initialization, appdelegate

In my iOS App I have an initial viewcontroller with 2 textfields for login.
If i run the application in debug mode code compiles good and i can see the initial viewcontroller that i set on my main storyboard.

In opposite if i try to run the code in **Release** the app crashes calming that the outlet are not set.

```
2017-04-07 13:55:53.422 Sahin Fruit[40068:1230157] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7fb5e2e0a450> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key emailTextField.'
```

To overcome the problem i tries to set the initial VC in AppDelegate programatically but no result, the app still crashes. Any idea?

```
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let initialViewController = UIStoryboard.viewControllerWithIdentifier(Main.loginVC.rawValue, storyBoardName: .Main)
    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

P.S: I turned off the optimisation in Release to see if that would help also no result.

Comment: problem in your inital VC, check once `emailTextField` connected or not

Comment: emailTextField is connected for sure, otherwise it would not work in debug =)

Comment: ensure once......

Comment: Key value coding is used during the initWithCoder phase. Something is wrong while instantiating the view controller which has corresponding storyboard resources.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you must have copied the ViewController in storyboard and assigned it different class. Just right click on the top of ViewController at the first square box(Forgot the exact name), and your extra outlet ll be shown with `yellow color triangle, just delete it` and your project will build fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have an old outlet that you deleted from code but still connected in the interface builder

Comment: see this once in question `In opposite if i try to run the code in Release the app crashes calming that the outlet are not set` not in `emailTextField is connected for sure, otherwise it would not work in debug`

Answer (score 0):

Check your references of your outlets in your Storyboard, one of them is probably referencing a property that does not exist anymore